# Drop down gets hidden

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, menu

I am creating a responsive site using bootstrap.

Now on mobile resolution we get a mobile menu.

This is the site where is it being coded:
http://www.myclientwebsites.com/UnderProgress/vssod/

To Reproduce/See what exactly is the issue:
Open the above site on mobile resolution. Click menu and hover on any drop down ex "Solutions" and the menu gets cutoff. This happens only first time.

Here is the screenshot of same:
http://tinypic.com/r/6nrz3a/5

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [z-index CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to assign a higher layer to the menu that is hidden by another div.

Comment: its not an issue with z index i guess. The vertical box is not expanding (the box the menu is enclosed)